# how to use NGINX for proxy RTMP

Tags: nginx, rtmp, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Im using NGINX for http proxy like below

```
http {
server {
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }
}
}
```

I would like to know anyway to use NGINX for RTMP something like

```
rtmp {
    server {
        server_name  example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass rtmp://localhost:1935;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.nginx.com/blog/video-streaming-for-remote-learning-with-nginx/

Comment: thanks but that not what I'm looking for. Basiclly, i have a NodeJS server running on rtmp://localhost:1935 so I just want forward rtmp://domain.com to rtmp://localhost:1935

Comment: have you tried `upstream` functionality on nginx?

Answer (score 2):

I have looked at Nginx documentation, below configuration can be useful. [Nginx TCP and UDP Load Balancing](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/)

```
stream {
    server {
        listen            3000;
        proxy_pass        localhost:1935;
        proxy_buffer_size 32k;
    }
}
```

Comment: For those getting an error on the 'stream' directive, this feature appears to be "NGINX Plus" only.

Comment: @DonPark Could you please point to the documentation that says it's only available in "NGINX Plus"? I was able to use it with the --with-stream configuration parameter. https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html

Comment: Upon closer inspection of the TCP Load balancing page linked above  the prereq shows "Latest NGINX Plus or latest NGINX Open Source built with the --with-stream configuration flag". I was getting an error from the stream directive which I took to mean its an NGINX+ feature but its more likely my nginx wasnt built with the stream module.

Answer (score 0):

@ismaildurmaz's answer was just about what I needed, but in my case I also wanted RTMPS (ie: RTMP over TLS).  This was accomplished with:

```
stream {
  server {
    listen            1935 ssl;
    proxy_pass        127.0.0.1:1936;
    proxy_buffer_size 32k; 

    ssl_certificate     /path/to/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl.key;
  }
}
```

Here, the upstream RTMP server is configured to listen on port **1936**, since nginx listens to port **1935** on all interfaces.